# Invalid handle with GetRawInputData, but only for Esc key-presses

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a bizarre problem in a raw input window proc that I can't figure out for the life of me.

Every time the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed, my code is hitting an 0x80004005 (invalid handle) exception on the first `GetRawInputData()` call.  It seems to only happen with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    switch ((WM)message.Msg)
    {
        case WM.INPUT:
        {
            if (message.LParam == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                break;
            }
            InputData rawBuffer;
            var dwSize = 0;
            //Invalid handle on this call, only with escape.
            var res = User32.GetRawInputData(message.LParam, DataCommand.RID_INPUT, IntPtr.Zero, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RawInputHeader)));
            if (res != 0)
            {
                var ex = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                Logger.Error(ex, "Error sizing the rawinput buffer: {0}", ex.Message);
                break;                           
            }

            res = User32.GetRawInputData(message.LParam, DataCommand.RID_INPUT, out rawBuffer, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RawInputHeader)));
            if (res == -1)
            {
                var ex = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                Logger.Error(ex, "Error getting the rawinput buffer: {0}", ex.Message);
                break;
            }
            if (res == dwSize)
            {
                foreach (var device in _devices)
                {
                    device.ProcessRawInput(rawBuffer);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Something is seriously f'd up with Windows - the number of bytes copied does not match the reported buffer size.
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

The struct definition:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RawInputHeader
{
    public uint dwType; 
    public uint dwSize;
    public IntPtr hDevice;
    public IntPtr wParam;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the window proc, or some weirdness around <kbd>Esc</kbd> and `GetRawInputData()` that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Could it be [`ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop'](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23f8fbb8-dcbc-4553-a353-8f609f542da7/escape-keydown-is-not-fired-in-wpf-window?forum=wpf)? And or [Sharing Message Loops Between Win32 and WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348549.aspx)?